# jQuery:Ajax Don't work loaded scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code :

```
//--Async load page

$("body").on("click", "a:not([data-noajax])", function(){
    href = $(this).attr("href");

    pageLoad(href + " .page-wrapper", ".page-wrapper", href);
    //$('#header').load(href+' #header');
    //$('#footer').load(href+' #footer');
    return false;
});

function pageLoad(from, where, href)
{

    href = typeof href === 'undefined' ? "" : href;
    loading();
    //$(where).empty();
    $(where).load(from, function(data){
        loading(false);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".page-header h1").offset().top }, "slow");

        title = $(".page-header h1").text();
        parent.location.hash = href;
        window.history.pushState($(document).html(), title, href);
        document.title = title;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.page-header h1').text(title);
        })
    });


}

//--
```

working, but....scripts which will load another page don't work (( 
example : go on the http://amour05.ru , click on some post title, and after try reload page;
first we don't see comments widget, and after reload we see it.

p.s. sorry for my english ((

RIGHT SOURCE CODE :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320"/>
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device_width, initial_scale=1.0" />
    <title>кто знает расписание пересдач ...</title>

    <style>
        body { padding-top: 60px;}
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/style.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/theme/style/jquery/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/scripts/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/scripts/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/scripts/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yandex.st/share/share.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?105"></script>

</head> 
<body>
<div class="page-wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <form id="search" action="/search.php" class="navbar-search pull-right" method="POST">
                    <input type="search" name="search_text" value="" class="search-query" placeholder="Поиск">
                </form>
                <a class="brand" href="/">amour05.ru</a>
                            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="container main">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="span3">
                <div class="well  well-sm">


    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">Меню</li>
        <li><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="active"><a id="add_post" href="/add.php">Добавить признание</a></li>
        <li><a href="/search.php">Поиск по сайту</a></li>
        <li><a id="feedback" href="/feedback.php">Написать админу</a></li>
    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="page-header well">
                    <h1>кто знает расписание пересдач ...</h1>
                </div>

                                <div class="well">


<div class="post">
    <div class="post_title"><h3 class="title">Анонимно</h3></div>
        <div class="post_text">
            кто знает расписание пересдач 3-его курса ЮФ пожалуйста скиньте.спасибо огромное)) <br><br>
        </div>

    <div class="post_data">
        <div style="text-align: center" class="yashare-auto-init" data-yashareL10n="ru"
         data-yashareQuickServices="yaru,vkontakte,facebook,twitter,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus" data-yashareTheme="counter"
         data-yashareTitle="кто знает расписание пересдач ..." data-yashareDescription ="кто знает расписание пересдач 3-его курса ЮФ пожалуйста скиньте.спасибо огромное)) <br><br>" ></div> 
    </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
  VK.init({apiId: 4092141, onlyWidgets: true});
</script>

<!-- Put this div tag to the place, where the Comments block will be -->
<div id="vk_comments"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 10, width: "100%", attach: "*", mini: "auto"}, 1560 );
VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.comments.new_comment", commentAdd);
VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.comments.delete_comment", commentDel);

function commentAdd(num, last, date, sign)
{

    $.post('/ajax.php',{
         type: 'vk_comment_add',
         num: num,
         last_comment: last,
         date: date,
         sign: sign,
         id: "1560"
    });


}
function commentDel(num, last, date, sign)
{

    $.post('/ajax.php',{
         type: 'vk_comment_del',
         num: num,
         last_comment: last,
         date: date,
         sign: sign,
         id: "1560"
    });


}
</script>


                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="well  well-sm">

    <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">Статистика</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li class="list-group-item">31.01.2014 18:58</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">комментариев : <span class="badge badge-info pull-right">0</span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">просмотров : <span class="badge badge-info pull-right">34</span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">уникальных : <span class="badge badge-info pull-right clearfix">10</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span6">


    <ul class="nav  hidden-phone">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li> <!-- Вертикальный разделитель -->
        <li><a href="about.php">О проекте</a></li>                
    </ul>

                    </div>

                    <div class="span6">


    <!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function (d, w, c) {
        (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() {
            try {
                w.yaCounter23555398 = new Ya.Metrika({id:23555398,
                        webvisor:true,
                        clickmap:true,
                        trackLinks:true,
                        accurateTrackBounce:true});
            } catch(e) { }
        });

        var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
            s = d.createElement("script"),
            f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); };
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.async = true;
        s.src = (d.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") + "//mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";

        if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
            d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
        } else { f(); }
    })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
    </script>
    <noscript><div><img src="//mc.yandex.ru/watch/23555398" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
    <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

GENERATED SOURCE :

```
<html data-savefrom-tab-data="{&quot;module&quot;:&quot;lm&quot;,&quot;tooltip&quot;:&quot;Найдено ссылок: 0&quot;}" lang="ru"><head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device_width, initial_scale=1.0">
    <title>кто знает расписание пересдач ...</title>

    <style>
        body { padding-top: 60px;}
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/jquery/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js" async="" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/scripts/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/scripts/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/scripts/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yandex.st/share/share.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?105"></script>

</head> 
<body data-savefrom-link-count="20" style="background-image: url(&quot;/theme/style/loveimgs/4.jpg&quot;);">
<div title="Загрузка" style="max-width: 500px;" id="loading" class="i hide"><img src="/theme/style/imgs/busy.gif" alt="загрузка"> идет загрузка</div><div class="page-wrapper"><div class="page-wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <form id="search" action="/search.php" class="navbar-search pull-right" method="POST">
                    <input name="search_text" value="" class="search-query" placeholder="Поиск" type="search">
                </form>
                <a class="brand" href="/">amour05.ru</a>
                            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="container main">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="span3">
                <div class="well  well-sm">


    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">Меню</li>
        <li><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="active"><a id="add_post" href="/add.php">Добавить признание</a></li>
        <li><a href="/search.php">Поиск по сайту</a></li>
        <li><a id="feedback" href="/feedback.php">Написать админу</a></li>
    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="page-header well">
                    <h1>кто знает расписание пересдач ...</h1>
                </div>

                                <div class="well">


<div class="post">
    <div class="post_title"><h3 class="title">Анонимно</h3></div>
        <div class="post_text">
            кто знает расписание пересдач 3-его курса ЮФ пожалуйста скиньте.спасибо огромное)) <br><br>
        </div>

    <div class="post_data">
        <div style="text-align: center" class="yashare-auto-init" data-yasharel10n="ru" data-yasharequickservices="yaru,vkontakte,facebook,twitter,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus" data-yasharetheme="counter" data-yasharetitle="кто знает расписание пересдач ..." data-yasharedescription="кто знает расписание пересдач 3-его курса ЮФ пожалуйста скиньте.спасибо огромное)) <br><br>"></div> 
    </div>
</div>





<!-- Put this div tag to the place, where the Comments block will be -->
<div id="vk_comments"></div>



                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="well  well-sm">

    <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">Статистика</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li class="list-group-item">31.01.2014 18:58</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">комментариев : <span class="badge badge-info pull-right">0</span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">просмотров : <span class="badge badge-info pull-right">26</span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">уникальных : <span class="badge badge-info pull-right clearfix">8</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span6">


    <ul class="nav  hidden-phone">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li> <!-- Вертикальный разделитель -->
        <li><a href="about.php">О проекте</a></li>                
    </ul>

                    </div>

                    <div class="span6">


    <!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->

    <noscript><div><img src="//mc.yandex.ru/watch/23555398" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
    <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>-->
</div></div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Whats your problem? Need to load commentbox on first view?

Comment: i need to load commentbox with ajax.

Comment: Are you using any plugin or any script to generate your comment box?

Comment: yes, //vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?105

Comment: Checkout this : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/. Should help

Comment: i don't know how it use for this situation ((